# How to convert 1080p to 1080i video using ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, video-conversion

I am using ffmpeg, trying to convert 1080p to 1080i. I know that `-vf tinterlace` should do that, but I don't know the exact syntax of use. Currently I'm trying this:

```
ffmpeg -i <input file.mp4> -c:v libx264 -c:a aac -vf tinterlace <output.mp4>
```

When I check the generated output in a video analyzer tool like Mediainfo, I see that it's still progressive. I know there must be some mistake in the command. I need both top fields first and bottom field first formats of interlacing to be applied to 1080p source video content.

Comment: Are you sure the mode you want is the right one? [`tincerlace`](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-all.html#tinterlace) has other modes that you might need. I'm thinking you need to supply another flag that tells x264 to do interlaced encoding, but I'm not sure at the moment. (Not a real fan of interlaced video—I avoid it wherever I can.)

Answer (score 1):

Try `-flags +ilme+ildct instead of -vf tinterlace`

Comment: Would you be able to give the entire command path?